# How to access custom folder inside bin folder in project C#

Tags: c#

Currently I got the full path for a folder inside my project. This is not sustainable in the long run. I need something like this

`var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);`

but instead of accessing the `bin/Debug` folder I want to access `bin/tessdata` folder (`tessdata` is the custom folder).

I have looked at some other posts but all of them end up in the `bin/Debug` folder.

This is how it should've worked from the very beginning 
`var ocr = new TesseractEngine("./tessdata", "eng", Tesseract.EngineMode.TesseractAndCube);` but I can't access the folder through `./tessdata`.

Does anyone have a solution to either of these two? Thanks!

**Edit**

Sorry, I have misunderstood the situation. I am actually trying to reach the `tessdata` folder inside the `bin/debug` folder inside another layer. The code is being run in that project but I didn't get that the the path went to the running project (the winform or webAPi projects). Basically  `Project\LicensePlate.Core\bin\Debug\tessdata`.

I apologize for the inconvenience, but still hope for some help if possible!

Comment: Why don't you use the config file to store this path? You can change it at your will when in debug on your dev pc or when you deploy your app to your customers

Comment: @Steve I didn't know this was possible, is this possible with the edit I did? Do you have a more detailed description? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the folder is always bin/tessdata just use:

```
var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) + "/../tessdata";
```

Otherwise make a task and copy `bin/tessdata` to `bin/debug/tessdata` durring compilation.

Comment: Made a change to the description, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: This solution still get you to the `bin/debug` + `/tessdata`. Noticed that my API project doesn't have a `bin/debug` so I can't get in to that folder.

Comment: Nvm, I didn't know what the dots were supposed to do. This didn't work because the `/` should be the other way - back slashes not front slashes. This works for my edit as well, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The

`var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);`

idea works very well to get where your application is running ( so the reason is in bin/Debug while launched from visual studio ), and will work even when deployed.
If the `./tesseractdata` folder is aside your executable, this is the way to go. Probably you find some inconsistency when debugging, this maybe is due you have the file in your solution in at the same level of the sources in a "`tesseractdata`" folder. If so, you can use the  "Copy to Output Directory" flag in the file properties in VS.

Comment: Made a change to the description, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: It is possible doing this way for the winform project but I don't have a `bin/debug` in my API project strangely enough :/

Answer (score 0):

You may write a function like below to get the executing assembly and search all files/folders. (here i mention about the file search from a folder from the `bin`
directory.

```
  public static string GetExternalToolsExecutablePath(string externalAssemblyName)
    {
        try
        {
            var assemblyLocation = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
            var directories = Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblyLocation);
            if (directories != null && Directory.Exists(directories))
            {
                var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directories);
                var executable = dirInfo.GetFiles(externalAssemblyName, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                    .Select(a => a.FullName).FirstOrDefault();
                return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(executable) ? executable : null;
            }
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Make sure you have copied the required files on every build, so use the build script to copy on every builds.

```
echo "Copy BIN FOLDER files..."
xcopy %ProjectDir%"XXXXXXXX\*.*" %TargetDir%"\XXXXXXX\" /Y /I /E /R>nul
```

In your case, you can alter the function a little as per your file types.

Comment: Made a change to the description, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: the above code is still valid for your edited description as well, 
make sure to do XCOPY for the file/folderName content to the build path (in your case its tessdata, and read the name from .config file) 
the function accepts the file name, and from there return the _Path.directory()_ for the path.

Answer (score 0):

Here your used a GetDirectoryName() function, It's return as location of assemble ( Directory + Location path your application Dll) and it's return type is string.

For your purpose use this following change in your code.

`var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) + "\\tessdata";`

It's return your excepted path location. but My Advise use environment variables else your will face some issue in other environments. Here is references of environment variable.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Made a change to the description, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: This solution still get you to the bin/debug + /tessdata. Noticed that my API project doesn't have a bin/debug so I can't get in to that folder. I'll look into the environment variable.