# Access folder from both webAPI project winform project C#

Tags: c#

I got a solution with several layers. One of these layers is the projectCore which handles all functionality (middle-layer in a 3 layer structure). There is a class there that handles reading images with ocr which both a webAPI project and a winform project runs against. To run the tesseract-ocr I have to access a tessdata folder.

So both project use this class and both get the same answer back.

[image]

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56002371/how-to-access-custom-folder-inside-bin-folder-in-project-c-sharp/56002629?noredirect=1#comment98653292_56002629) question yesterday and got lots of answers on how to reach the folder which were at the time above the bin/debug folders one reaches with `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)`.

We solved it like this
`var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) + @"\..\..\..\tessdata";`. But I noticed now when I ran the API project that the coderow only works with the winform project at the moment and not the api project.

This is how the method looks now but the first row wont work when posting to the api.

[image]

The solution is up on azure devops and the API is published on azure as well so the file needs to be accessed when run on another computer or over the server really.

**Where would be the best place to put this `tessdata` folder so that both projects can access it during runtime? And how do I access this folder?**

Comment: If I understand, it sounds like you want to create a windows folder share so the folder is accessible. There are implications regarding networking and access control so I can't say this is your answer.

Comment: As I edited this folder can't be accessed locally from my computer. If it is in the solution folder shouldn't the folder still be accessible? :/ @Crowcoder

Comment: There is no solution folder for a deployed application so you have to think beyond your development environment. Reading closer, I see you are using Unity to hit an API. You won't be able to access the same folder from both the Unity app and the API. I don't claim to fully understand your requirements but maybe you just want the data on the API side and expose it through HTTP to the Unity client.

Comment: The tessdata folder is only to be accessed in my `services` class  under the core-layer and it is only used for some ocr. Both the winform and the api project are running against this `services`. Why can't the core-layer just access this tessdata-folder so it can access it easily by a row of code -.- Am I doing this way too complicated? @Crowcoder

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess I don't understand clearly your project structure or what you are doing.

Comment: @Crowcoder No I'm sorry for my very bad explanation. I did an edit if it makes it any clearer